# console.log(ctx.drawimage(...)) outputs undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use the HTML canvas in .js to output an image. Easy enough. Pretty sure it should be working. But, it's not. So, I tried doing a console.log of the ctx.drawImage method. It returns undefined. Is that normal? Should it be printing my image? What's going on?

Also, here's my code, if you're interested:

```
let c = document.createElement("canvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = 752;
c.height = 386;
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
let TopPadding = 106; // Distance from top of slide
let leftSidePadding = 650;
let imageHeight = 45;
let imageWidth = 46;

let img = new Image();
img.src = 'app/resources/Uploaded/Info.png';
console.log(img);
img.onload = () => {
    console.log(ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
    ctx.drawImage(img, leftSidePadding, TopPadding, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    console.log('Hello, Martian!!');
};
  
console.log('Hello, Earthling!!');
```

Comment: The return type is of `drawImage()` is void - so it doesn't return anything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Would it print my image then? If not, why?

Comment: `drawImage` performs an action on the Context2D. Of course you will only be able to see the result when if the canvas element is in the DOM and visible. This operation doesn't return any result though, so console has nothing to print. Also, console will not draw images painted in the Context2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add your canvas to the HTML document! :)

```
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
```

Also, the undefined is probably expected; I do not think drawImage returns anything.

Comment: There was one other line of code: ```tml3dRenderer.setTexture("LargeInstructionInfoImage", c.toDataURL());``` I think this does that

Comment: To clarify - I pasted your code into a new document and added the 'appendChild' line above the drawImage line. It got it working for me (with obvious image src change)

Comment: Check the source HTML of your output, if you see the canvas already there, then I am wrong :)

Comment: In Chromium, that would F12 and then Elements, correct? It seems that because of the IDE I'm using and the built preview of what I've built, all that I can see of the HTML code is the preview itself. I already have one canvas working, and it's not showing up on the Elements page. Thanks for the try